# Installing Xenon headlights in 2004 Chrysler Sebring

Tags: headlight, hid, chrysler, retrofit

I was thinking about installing Xenon headlights in my car. I hate other drivers who have them because I go blind, but after riding in my friends car equipped with them, I'm more than ready to take the hate.

My car is equipped with standard Halogen bulbs. I think that this means that in order to use Xenon bulbs, I'll need all the inverter electronics in order to ionize the gas and whatnot.

I found [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003FXVJSQ) kit on Amazon and I was wondering if it's the appropriate solution. I asked a salesperson at O'Reilly autoparts here in town if $20 sounded appropriate, and he said he would guess it would cost a lot more but sometimes you can find good deals.

If this isn't what I'll need, can anyone send me in the right direction?

Comment: You might want to consider editing your question to remove the blurb about price so your question isn't closed as being too localized.  Price is limited to certain geographic areas and may change by next year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered this same question here:

[Kia Soul aftermarket headlights](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/351/kia-soul-aftermarket-headlights)

bottom line:  HID retrofit = bad idea unless your projectors are made for them. You WILL blind oncoming drivers. If HID is an option from the factory for the Sebring, I would get those housings rather than retrofitting your existing halogen setup.

Here is a [good (though exhaustive) read](http://www.danielsternlighting.com/tech/bulbs/Hid/conversions/conversions.html) on the pitfalls of HID retrofits.

Answer (score 3):

Similarly to NoCarrier, I answered a similar question on [Upgrading a Jeep Wrangler to HID lights](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/63/upgrade-to-hid-lights-in-a-jeep-wrangler).

In my experience, those HID lights that "blind you" are the ones done aftermarket and I don't believe they're legal.  If your friend has a factory kit, you will likely notice that the lights have a very strong cut-off point, they really only illuminate the road and don't shine into oncoming traffic.  The cost of doing it right is, from what I've seen, several thousand dollars.  See the other discussions for details of why.